# is there any way to access directroy live like in airdroid app with remote ip address (not on local network ) in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I am just making an app that allow file sharing from android device to PC. I just want to access the directory just like in AirDroid app.
please help me and guide regarding this. My main topic of discussion is to access directory over the global ip not just on local ip addresss just like es file explorer do (open an ftp port and give us a link to see and share directory in web browser).

Thank You!

I already have used the ftp libray to open a port and share the files on local and same network but i an not able to access the directory over the different networks.Please guide me how can i achieve this and if there is a complete guide or source code is available for this purpose.

in short I want to access directory over different netwrok ip address as i access with in local network with local ip address

Comment: If you made an ftp server app on your Android device and your Android device is connected (using wifi) to a router than you should on your pc use the internet ip addrss of that router. And on the router go to its settings and forward port 21 (i believe it is 21) to the local ip addess of your Android device.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks for your response. Is this port forwarding method work with the scenario if my android device (on which I have installed my ftp server app)  is connected with some 4g data connection and I want to access (connect) it to my PC which is connected to my wifi router connection instead of connecting with that 4G network to which my android is connected.
means to say if both device are on different networks then connectivity is still possible ?
please guide me regarding this . I am very confused about this topic and stuck on it.   please .thank you sooo much.

Comment: If you use 4G than you do not use a router. (Well your android device does not. Your pc is still connected to a router). So there is no portforwarding to do.Inpriciple the pc could directly use the internet address the device uses during 4G. But... sadly.. your provider usually blocks incoming traffic. The servers you run are not reacheable from outside world if using 3G, 4G and so on. To be reacheable your device should use wifi and a router.

Comment: `and I want to access (connect) it to my PC`. It is the other way round. An appkication on your pc would try to connect with the server on your device. Servers do not connect. Clients do. Servers listen and wait for connections.